# How do I measure performance of elisp code?

Tags: performance, benchmarking

How do I measure the performance of my elisp code? What tools / external packages are available for me to measure time taken?

In addition to total time, can I see a profile that shows time taken per-function? Can I profile memory usage too?

Comment: The question is too broad. What kind of performance? Where? When? "***Emacs performance***" can mean anything and everything.

Comment: @Drew Many other programming languages have a set of benchmarks (e.g. Python: http://speed.pypy.org/, JS: Sunspider etc), and I was hoping that there was an equivalent for the elisp interpreter.

Comment: Benchmarking such as that provided by function `benchmark` and the profiler does not measure **Emacs** performance. It measures the performance evaluating particular expressions. It is helpful in comparing performances *within* Emacs. To measure the performance of Emacs itself you would need to compare it to the performance of something other than Emacs. And that is where the breadth of Emacs comes into play. You could measure Emacs vs XYZ for this or that, but to measure Emacs performance as a whole you would need umpteen such comparisons.

Comment: Maybe you meant "*How do I measure performance in Emacs*"?

Comment: I'm interested in answering the question 'is Emacs 24.4 faster than 24.3?' or 'how much faster would Guile-Emacs be than the GNU Emacs 24.3?'. I'm not sure how to proceed, as the answers here are interesting (and a good start), but not what I had in mind.

Comment: That's what I mean. Comparing two Emacs versions is too broad (IMO). You could reasonably try to compare two versions for some specific operation. For that, you will need, I think, to compare processor and memory use or clock time or some such. And for that you might need tools that are outside Emacs. Same thing for trying to compare such things across platforms. I don't have an answer for you, and I think the question is too broad. But maybe you will get some help for what you need.

Comment: Why not just benchmark a set of common operations separately on Emacs 24.4 and 24.3 and then compare which took the longest?

Comment: I admit I think I misread your question. I read it as _“How do I benchmark Emacs Lisp?”_. On a separate note, the question at the end _“Are there any benchmarks of Emacs performance?”_ sounds quite different from _“How do I benchmark Emacs?”_.

Comment: OK, I've opened http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/655/304 to be about benchmarking Emacs, and reworded this question be about benchmarking/profiling elisp programs.

Answer (score 35):

#### Benchmark

The most straightforward options is the built-in [`benchmark`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/benchmark) package.
Its usage is remarkably simple:

```
(benchmark 100 (form (to be evaluated)))
```

It’s autoloaded, so you don’t even need to require it.

#### Profiling

Benchmark is good at overall tests, but if you’re having performance
problems it doesn’t tell you which functions are causing the problem.
For that, you have the (also built-in) [profiler](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/profiler-start).

1. Start it with `M-x profiler-start`.
2. Do some time consuming operations.
3. Get the report with `M-x profiler-report`.

You should be taken to a buffer with a navigatable tree of function calls.
[image: Profiler screenshot]

Comment: `benchmark` function doesn't seem to work: when I do inside an opened `.c` file `(benchmark 100 (c-font-lock-fontify-region 0 17355))`, I keep getting `void-function jit-lock-bounds`.

Comment: FTR: as an alternative to `benchmark` there are functions `benchmark-run` and `benchmark-run-compiled`. For me the main difference was that both functions actually work *(see the prev. comment)* :Ь

Answer (score 16):

In addition to @Malabara's answer, I tend to use a custom-made `with-timer` macro to permanently instrument various parts of my code (e.g my `init.el` file).

The difference is that while `benchmark` allows to study the performance of a specific bit of code that you instrument, `with-timer` always gives you the time spent in each instrumented part of the code (without much overhead for sufficiently large parts), which gives you the input to know which part should be investigated further.

```
(defmacro with-timer (title &rest forms)
  "Run the given FORMS, counting the elapsed time.
A message including the given TITLE and the corresponding elapsed
time is displayed."
  (declare (indent 1))
  (let ((nowvar (make-symbol "now"))
        (body   `(progn ,@forms)))
    `(let ((,nowvar (current-time)))
       (message "%s..." ,title)
       (prog1 ,body
         (let ((elapsed
                (float-time (time-subtract (current-time) ,nowvar))))
           (message "%s... done (%.3fs)" ,title elapsed))))))
```

Example use:

```
(with-timer "Doing things"
  (form (to (be evaluated))))
```

yielding the following output in the `*Messages*` buffer:

```
Doing things... done (0.047s)
```

---

I should mention that this is heavily inspired by Jon Wiegley's `use-package-with-elapsed-timer` macro in his excellent [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) extension.

Comment: If you're measuring init.el, you will probably be interested in [the emacs startup profiler](https://github.com/jschaf/esup).

Comment: Macros are awesome. This deserves more votes.

Comment: Emacs records the total init time.  You can show it with the command `emacs-init-time`.

Comment: @WilfredHughes yes, I do use `esup` and I like it. But once again, the interest of such a thing as `with-timer` is not so much to profile something thorougly. The real interest is that you *always* have profiling information. Whenever I start emacs, I have a buch of lines in my `*Messages*` buffer that tell me which part took how long. If I detect anything abnormal, I can then use any of the more adequate tools to profile and optimize things.

Comment: @JoeS Yes, `emacs-init-time` does produce interesting information. However, it only gives an inclusive elapsed time, without the possibility to break down individual parts of the initialization.

Comment: Error message: "Symbol’s function definition is void: form", Emacs v25.2.1

Comment: There's also the [benchmark-init.el](https://github.com/dholm/benchmark-init-el) package.

Comment: You can also use the `elp` profiler.  Try `M-x elp-instrument- TAB`. and later `M-x elp-results`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Malabarba's answer, note that you can measure the *compiled* execution time of your code with `benchmark-run-compiled`.  That metric is often much more relevant than the *interpreted* execution time that `M-x benchmark` gives you:

```
ELISP> (benchmark-run (cl-loop for i below (* 1000 1000) sum i))
(0.79330082 6 0.2081620540000002)

ELISP> (benchmark-run-compiled (cl-loop for i below (* 1000 1000) sum i))
(0.047896284 0 0.0)
```

The three numbers are the total elapsed time, the number of GC runs, and the time spent in GC.

Answer (score 1):

Benchmarking is not only about getting the numbers, it is also about making decisions based on result analysis.

There is [benchstat.el](https://melpa.org/#/benchstat) package on MELPA which you can use to get features that [benchstat](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/perf/cmd/benchstat) program provides.

It implements comparison-based benchmarking where you examine `X` performance properties against `Y`.

Benchstat functions can be viewed as a `benchmark-run-compiled` wrapper that not only collects the information, but gives it back in easy to read an interpret format. It includes:

- Elapsed time delta between `X` and `Y`
- Mean average time
- Allocations amount

Very simple usage example:

```
(require 'benchstat)

;; Decide how much repetitions is needed.
;; This is the same as `benchmark-run-compiled` REPETITIONS argument.
(defconst repetitions 1000000)

;; Collect old code profile.
(benchstat-run :old repetitions (list 1 2))
;; Collect new code profile.
(benchstat-run :new repetitions (cons 1 2))

;; Display the results.
;; Can be run interactively by `M-x benchstat-compare'.
(benchstat-compare)
```

The `benchstat-compare` will render results in a temporary buffer:

```
name   old time/op    new time/op    delta
Emacs    44.2ms ± 6%    25.0ms ±15%  -43.38%  (p=0.000 n=10+10)

name   old allocs/op  new allocs/op  delta
Emacs      23.0 ± 0%      11.4 ± 5%  -50.43%  (p=0.000 n=10+10)
```

You will need `benchstat` program binary though.
If you used Go programming language, most likely you have one in your
system already. 
Otherwise there is an option of compiling it from the sources.

Precompiled binary for linux/amd64 can be found at [github release page](https://github.com/Quasilyte/benchstat.el/releases).