# Profile a command by wall time

Tags: profiler

The `profiler-start` command has options for `cpu`, `mem`, and `cpu+mem`. Is there a way to profile a command by elapsed time?

Comment: Related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/539/50

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do that using *profiler.el* as it is a sampling profiler. It's not actually measuring how long a function takes to run, it's periodically checking to see what function is currently being executed, and adding up all of those samples.

ELP or the [EmacsLispProfiler](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsLispProfiler) is an instrumenting compiler. To enable instrumentation use <kbd>M-x</kbd> *elp-instrument-function* on one or more functions. After running code that calls the instrumented functions, run <kbd>M-x</kbd> *elp-results*. This will display a buffer showing the total number of calls and elapsed time for each instrumented function. Check out <kbd>M-x find-libary</kbd> *elp* for more information.

If you know exactly what function you want to profile, the benchmark library might also be useful.

Answer (score 5):

You can use
[`benchmark`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/benchmark) to
determine how long a command takes.

```
(benchmark 100 (command))
```

100 is the number of repetitions, make it large enough for you results
to be meaningful. And don’t forget you can also call it interactively.

> (benchmark REPETITIONS FORM)
>
> Print the time taken for REPETITIONS executions of FORM.
>   Interactively, REPETITIONS is taken from the prefix arg.

You can also use it for any arbitrary form, not just a single command.

```
(benchmark 100 (form to (be evaluated))
```