# Portable Emacs: Remapping user-emacs-directory

Tags: init-file, start-up, invocation

### The Problem

I want to install Emacs on a USB Flash Drive in a *portable fashion*, that is, Emacs should be able to be run from the UFD, once plugged on a device, without predefined paths to its binaries and save all its persistent data on the UFD.
To obtain this, the Emacs startup script (possibly in the form of an icon for the user to click on) should be able to find the relevant binaries and set the needed directory paths.

Hereafter I take Windows as an example, but my concepts are not platform-specific.

In Windows 90% of the work for a portable Emacs is already done by [GNU Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html), because Emacs for Windows comes as a zipped package, without an installer. According to the docs you have to:

> Unzip the zip file preserving the directory structure, and run `bin\runemacs.exe`. Alternatively, create a desktop shortcut to `bin\runemacs.exe`, and start Emacs by double-clicking on that shortcut's icon.

Anyway, when extracting on a UFD, *persistent data will not be stored on the UFD*, but on the home directory of the host system.

### This is what I tried

Let us assume that Emacs has been extracted as `emacs` on the root of the UFD,  where  there is also a `docs` folder. In the root I therefore create the following batch script to bootstrap Emacs:

```
Emacs.cmd
---------
set "HOME=%~dp0docs"
emacs\bin\runemacs.exe   -q   --load emacs\init.el %*
```

**Script Explanation**
`-q` solves side effects due to unwanted  reading/writing of init files on the host system.
At the same time, this requires that some *init file equivalent* is manually loaded with the `--load` part. An alternative would be using `site-start.el`, not bypassed by `-q`.
Note that paths are relative to the position of the script so there is no need to guess the UFD drive letter. 
The same is not true for the home dir. In this case I use the `%~dp0` trick, which is converted by the shell to the script parent dir (somewhat like `$(dirname "$0")` in Bash).
`%*` lets add add extra arguments to `runemacs`, when running `Emacs.cmd` from the console.
Given `-q` is intended to make a slimmer Emacs, some default settings might be missing and if you need them you have to manually set them in `emacs\init.el`. By reading superficially Emacs `startup.el` code, one such missing item is:

```
(package-initialize)
```

which should be added to `emacs\init.el` or alternatively to `site-start.el`

This setup works pretty well. So now I come to the actual

### Question

In the setup above, where the `HOME` dir is used to store documents,  therefore it would be nice and make sense to have the Emacs settings directory, `.emacs.d`, outside the document folder.

According to the documentation it should be possible to obtain this result by properly setting the variable `user-emacs-directory`. Therefore, the following lines should be added to the head of the init file called by the bootstrap script:

```
init.el 
-------
(setq user-emacs-directory
      (expand-file-name (concat invocation-directory "../.emacs.d")))
(setq abbrev-file-name
      (locate-user-emacs-file "abbrev_defs"))
(setq auto-save-list-file-prefix
      (locate-user-emacs-file "auto-save-list/.saves-"))
(cd "~"))
```

Despite the `-q` switch, before running `init.el` other code is run  (this is why the abbreviations and the auto-save directory require a separate setup).

These settings work only partially. In fact, an empty `~/.emacs.d` keeps appearing in the home dir.
*What library creates the folder?* 
Is it possible to avoid to make the `HOME` folder dirty?

Debugging `startup.el` would help, but it is not possible, as  it is a *fake* file. Its actual content is dumped into the Emacs binary.

Comment: I would try setting HOME before starting Emacs and then at the end of init setting it back.

Comment: @glucas: To be sure I got it. Do you mean setting a temp HOME in the shell script, acting as the parent for `.emacs.d`, and the real HOME in my pseudo-init like: 
`(setenv "HOME" 
      (expand-file-name (concat invocation-directory "../../doc")))`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking.

Comment: @glucas: Before posting I read a similar [question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/4253/3975) looking just for a custom `user-emacs-directory`, not necessarily outside `HOME`. @phil [suggested](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/how-to-start-emacs-with-a-custom-user-emacs-directory#comment9059_4255) this idea of a dynamic `HOME`, but it does not work. Emacs can't find system/config files any more and, when it absolutely needs to write config files, it consequently stalls. Anyway, since I don't see other possiblities, I am determined to investigate this path. ... will let u know`

Comment: Another idea: can you just use mklink to temporarily mount your emacs init dir to ~/.emacs.d?

Comment: @glucas: If I can avoid links it is better, because I could use drag and drop to easily move the distro on new computers or UFD drives.  Everything seems to work with the proposed solution. Just I am thinking to move the --load pseudo-init content in site-start.el, to load from there a user init file (to overcome the `-q` switch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution based on suggestions by [@phil](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/how-to-start-emacs-with-a-custom-user-emacs-directory#comment9059_4255) and [@glucas](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26121/portable-emacs-user-emacs-directory#comment39685_26121).

The idea is to set a dynamic `HOME` variable: first set it in the shell as the parent of `.emacs.d`; then reset it in  my "pseudo-init" to the desired value (here the document folder).
Here is the full working solution.

**Solution**:

```
Emacs.cmd
---------
set "HOME=%~dp0\emacs"
emacs\bin\runemacs.exe   -q   --load emacs\init.el %*

init.el 
-------
(setq user-emacs-directory
      (expand-file-name (concat invocation-directory "../.emacs.d")))
(setenv "HOME"
        (expand-file-name (concat invocation-directory "../../docs")))
(setq abbreviated-home-dir (concat 
                    "\\`" 
                (getenv "HOME")
                "\\(/\\|\\'\\)"))
(setq abbrev-file-name
      (locate-user-emacs-file "abbrev_defs"))
(setq auto-save-list-file-prefix
      (locate-user-emacs-file "auto-save-list/.saves-"))
(cd "~"))
```

**Comments**

As explained in the question, `%~dp0\emacs` stands for `<script parent dir>\emacs` (of course with Windows slashes). `emacs` is the Emacs install folder and also the designated parent for `.emacs.d`.
Since `.emacs.d` is supposed to be a subidir of `HOME`, Emacs  will set it  automatically.

After starting Emacs and launching my pseudo-init via the *relative* path  `--load emacs\init.el`,  the original value of `user-emacs-directory`, that is `"~/.emacs.d/"`,  is reset to:

```
(setq user-emacs-directory
      (expand-file-name (concat invocation-directory "../.emacs.d")))
```

The new path is relative to the Emacs invocation directory and outside `HOME`. `HOME` is reset to the document dir:

```
(setenv "HOME"
        (expand-file-name (concat invocation-directory "../../docs")))
```

As observed in my question, before starting the pseudo-init, other code is run. Therefore, at this level 
`(locate-user-emacs-file "foo")` would report `"~\\.emacs.d\\foo"`. Beside this  being not what is desired,  `"~\\.emacs.d"` is not existent.  The `locate-user-emacs-file` function is used by Emacs for reading and writing config files, which would become therefore impossible.

In fact, it turns out that, before starting the init files, Emacs sets `abbreviated-home-dir`. In our case the variable is set to the old shell value, different from `(setenv "HOME" ...` above. 
The wrong `abbreviated-home-dir` causes `(abbreviate-file-name user-emacs-directory)` to return the undesired  `"~/.emacs.d"`. `abbreviated-home-dir`  is used by `locate-user-emacs-file`, which ultimately breaks everything.

To fix this misbehaviour, `abbreviated-home-dir`  is reset to the new `HOME` in

```
(setq abbreviated-home-dir ...   (getenv "HOME") ...
```

To understand why the value is encapsulated in those weird strings, check the documentation with  `C-h v abbreviated-home-dir`.

`abbrev-file-name` and `auto-save-list-file-prefix` are also set before the pseudo-init call. So they need to be reset to good values.

Answer (score 3):

The patch which allows you to specify .emacs.d location via `EMACS_USER_DIRECTORY' environment variable is available in https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15539 but it's not yet merged.

Comment: the patch is very nice, the problem is that developers are not willing to merge it.

Comment: wow. as of 2019 there is still ongoing discussion on that mailing list thread ("setting user-emacs-directory") which began in 2013!

Comment: It seems like devs have finally came to their senses and did the right thing https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=4118297ae2fab4886b20d193ba511a229637aea3

Comment: Finally, in Emacs 29 (2022): `--init-directory=DIR        use DIR when looking for the Emacs init files`! Yay.