# how to use multiple emacs distributions?

Tags: init-file, config

I'd like to use multiple emacs distributions e.g. spacemacs, prelude, starter-kit and my personal config for demonstration purposes.

What would be some recommended ways to realize this?

Comment: Are you essentially after using multiple init files? If so, I found that the easiest way is to have multiple users (simple to do on Linux), where everyone would have their own home directory with dedicated configuration.

Comment: "**How to start up emacs with different configurations**":  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568042/how-to-start-up-emacs-with-different-configurations

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Use several Emacs configurations/versions simultaneously](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36380/use-several-emacs-configurations-versions-simultaneously)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19936/780